# search user by username in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**views.py**

```
class CreateUserM(CreateModelMixin, ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = User.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(username__search=query)
        return qs

class Updareuser(UpdateModelMixin, RetrieveAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        username = self.kwargs['pk']
        return User.objects.filter(id=username)

    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

**url.py**

```
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', CreateUserM.as_view(), name='list_view'),
        url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', Updareuser.as_view(), name='list_vfiew'),

]
```

I want to search a user by its username but this code has some errors when I filtering by id it works but about the other things have an error I changed the *Django User model* with **OneToOnefield**.

Comment: what errors are you getting ? and use __icontains instead of __search because it support only in mysql

Comment: What do you mean by username? You are assigning pk to the username variable. Edit your question and make it more clear. Indicate in what line error occurs.

Comment: If you're using the standard User model for django, then you're mixing up id and username. The pk is id, which will be a number. If you've made changes to the User model, please post what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

Or also you can do like this

from django.db.models import Q

def home(request):
if request.GET.get('q') != None:
q = request.GET.get('q')
else:
q = ''

```
rooms = Room.objects.filter(
    Q(host__username__icontains = q)               
    )

topics = Topic.objects.all()

context = {'rooms': rooms, 'topics':topics}
return render(request, 'base/home.html', context)
```